# Import excel in field collection items

Tags: importing-exporting, entities

I m using field collection items in my content type for particular upload function.

I want to use import excel feature to bulk upload with field collection item fields.

**when i click on import excel upload button the field collection fields filled with excel data.**

Can anyone help me, how to achieve this feature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the **f[ield collection feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_feeds)**? It does exactly what you are looking for.

> Provides feeds integration for field collection module.
>   Require Feeds alpha7 or later version.

Comment: I tried this module, but showing the error    "An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: /gigabyte/batch?id=337&op=do StatusText: OK ResponseText: Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in /opt/lampp/htdocs/gigabyte/includes/common.inc on line 7998". I upload it my feeds xls parser. **what is entity host id, field identifier and item id?. I simply mapped the fields in my field collection item.** Can u tell me how to configure the filed collection processor.     Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It takes few minutes to get things right. The detailed setup manual is available here. Be patient and sef things up well.

I just used it 3 days ago.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1831004

Comment: I tried as same in the post. Even though I'm getting the error while importing. **Unable to save a field collection item without a valid reference to a host entity.**    Thanks.

Comment: is field host entity id should be nid or what?